# Как настроить NTP сервер без доступа в интернет?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, unix, администрирование

Здравствуйте.Имеется парк серверов и машин в вакууме, без доступа во внешние сети.
Необходимо один свервер настрить как ntp севрер, остальные(Linux и Windows) машины как клиенты.
Вопросы!
- Стоит ли поднимать два ntp сервера? если они разойдутся во времени непонятно кому верить.
- Что прописывать у ntp севреа в качестве его сервера? ему же нескем синхронизироваться!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае если ntp сервер локальный, без выхода в инетрнет , то надо задаать ему соответствующий starum, примерно 10, так как все кто будет тянуть с него время будут уже starum 11 и так делее до 16!

Если его не задать то ntp клиенты буду считать его starum 16 и не смогут брать с него время.

ntp севреру  прописываем в качестве его севрера для синхронизации:

server 127.127.1.0
fudge  127.127.1.0 stratum 10

все.

Answer (score 3):

> Вопросы! - Стоит ли поднимать два ntp сервера?

Если есть вероятность, что сервер может упасть, то да, подымайте. Если у Вас полторы машины... то нет смысла.

> если они разойдутся во времени непонятно кому верить.

так пусть один будет "старший", а второй будет синкаться от него.

> Что прописывать у ntp севреа в качестве его сервера? ему же нескем синхронизироваться!

если внешнего интернета совсем-совсем нет, тогда нечего и прописывать. Но тогда Вам придется приходить время от времени с эталонными часами и верифицировать.

Comment: придется приходить с эталонными часами и верифицировать, имеется ввиду переодически подправлять время на ntp сервере?

Comment: да. Вам придется самостоятельно выступать этим сервером синхронизации. Но есть несколько обходных путей. К примеру, сервером синхронизации для ntp может выступать Ваш ноут. А прийдя домой, Вы всегда его засинкаете. Точность может хромать, но автоматизация.  А можно по сигналам точного времени синхронизироваться.